# LD1117 vs LM1117

Tags: capacitor, input

If I'm driving, say, a 500mA load, would you guys think that I could use these two parts more or less interchangeably?

http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=-1011&y=-71&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=LM1117T-3.3%2FNOPB-ND

http://www.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&lang=en&keywords=LD1117V33C&x=-943&y=-51&cur=USD

Specifically, in regard to input capacitors, would both be fine with 10uF?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do the datasheets say about using 10 uF?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are pretty much the same, just versions from different manufacturers. It's very common for older parts like this for each manufacturer to make their own version (I assume once the [initial patent has expired](http://www.edn.com/electronics-news/4315075/Checklist-When-does-a-patent-expire-))
Both require a minimum 10uF on the output. All info and example circuits are provided in the datasheets, read them thoroughly ;-)